# How to change windows self extraction location?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am trying to deploy a WSUS role on a server but in the installation stage the wizard tries to extract a file to a drive which does not have permission.

[image]

Can you help me to change this to C drive?.

Comment: Hey please can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that windows can't create a folder on a drive. You should take a look at the drive's security settings and verify SYSTEM has access to it.

if for some reason you can't / won't give windows access to the drive, then it looks like n: is the drive with most free space (as far as I can remember windows uses the drive with most free space). If that's the case, I'd suggest temporarily removing it's drive letter via diskmgmt.msc, or filling it up for a while.